# Link overlap, on target port

Tags: jointjs

I have an issue with link, on target port device, it unusually overlaps the target port.... check my [`fiddle`](https://jsfiddle.net/blablabla/73se0h6d/) . I also have attached a screenshot [overlap image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PNz0y.png). Someone have any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think JointJS is calculating that your source and target should be considered an obstacle. Adding the `excludeEnds` option in your fiddle seems to resolve the issue. You can see the option in the following docs.
https://resources.jointjs.com/docs/jointjs/v3.5/joint.html#routers.manhattan

Your code example could be the following:

```js
var link = new joint.dia.Link({
    // source: { id: el1.id },
    // target: { id: el2.id },
    router: { name: 'manhattan', args: {  excludeEnds: ['source', 'target'] } },
    connector: { name: 'rounded' },
    attrs: {
        '.connection': {
            stroke: 'red',
            'stroke-width': 5
        },
        '.marker-target': {
            fill: 'red',
            d: 'M 10 0 L 0 5 L 10 10 z'
        },
        '.marker-source': { /*stroke: '#fe854f',*/ fill: 'red', d: 'M 10 0 L 0 5 L 10 10 z' },
    }
});
```